# How to set settings.LOGIN_URL to a view function name in Django 1.5+

Tags: python, django, authentication

As of Django 1.5, you can set [LOGIN_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#login-url) to a view function name, but I haven't been able to figure out how to specify it correctly.

```
LOGIN_URL = my_app.views.sign_in
```

...does not work. I get the error,

```
ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

Comment: You have to give a non-empty value to `settings.SECRET_KEY` variable, like `SECRET_KEY = '1234567890'`. That's what the exception is telling you.

Comment: The SECRET_KEY error was caused by a problematic import statement.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Django computes this url in django.contrib.auth.views:redirect_to_login function as:

```
resolved_url = resolve_url(login_url or settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

Therefore you should set it as string:

```
LOGIN_URL = 'my_app.views.sign_in'
```

Also in settings.py you can use reverse_lazy function:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('my_app.views.sign_in')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy

Comment: That will work, but it doesn't take advantage of the new feature in 1.5, does it?

Comment: Hmm... yes, I updated answer. And check that settings.SECRET_KEY is not empty.

Comment: For some reason the first time I tried this solution, it simply put my_app.views.sign_in on the URL. But after going back and retrying it, it works fine now. <shrug> The SECRET_KEY error was caused by an import statement that create some circular problems.

Comment: In my settigns I set `LOGIN_URL = 'path.views.MyView'` however it doesnt change anything. It seems it is never called. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want to link the `LOGIN_URL` to the "view" (you can change on other), then you can link to the named URL in `settings.py`:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('login')
```

where "login" is something like:

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'my_app.view.Login', name='login'),
```

then, if you change the view on the other, you don't need to make changes in `settings.py`

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you've set the path name in `urls.py`, you can use `'application_name:view_name'` as the `LOGIN_URL` value in `settings.py`, like so:

**application/urls.py**

```
...
path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
...
```

**project/settings.py**

`LOGIN_URL = 'application:login'`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#login-url

Answer (score 2):

Django 2.1.5

```
django.urls import reverse_lazy
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('namespace of any url used in your project ')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the view in the project root ( not inside an app ) you just specify the view name in settings.py:

...

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

...